# How to convert Document object to file stream object without saving physically

Tags: c#, file, stream

I used following code to convert the "doc" object to convert the file stream. 
Instead of saving the doc object on physical path, Is it possible to convert the  memory object "doc" to the file stream object?

```
Application word = new Application();
doc = new Document();
doc = word.Documents.Open(destFile);
doc.Activate();
Set_Document_Bookmarks_Values(); 
doc.SaveAs2(destFile);
doc.Close();
word.Quit();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: I assume this is C#... But you may wish to specify this in your question...

Comment: Yes its C# code

Comment: Can you update your question with the exception that you are encountering?

Comment: A `FileStream` object represents a physical file, you can't not save to a physical file and use a `FileStream`.  If you want one in memory, use a `MemoryStream`.